# Magento2 : Zend_Json_Exception : Decoding failed: Syntax error in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, exception, json

I have a `custom module` which is working perfectly in my local machine but while I am trying to enable my module in my `magento 2`store hosted in `cPanel`,

I am getting below error

```
> bbcmanagement@billionaireboysclub.com [~/public_html]# **php bin/magento module:enable -v  BBC_ProductAdminAccess**

>ea-php-cli Copyright 2017 cPanel, Inc.

>  [Zend_Json_Exception]   Decoding failed: Syntax error
> Exception trace:  () at /home/bbcmanagement/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Json.php:97 Zend_Json::decode() at /home/bbcmanagement/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Module/PackageInfo.php:85 Magento\Framework\Module\PackageInfo->load() at /home/bbcmanagement/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Module/PackageInfo.php:208 Magento\Framework\Module\PackageInfo->getRequire() at /home/bbcmanagement/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Module/DependencyChecker.php:132 Magento\Framework\Module\DependencyChecker->createGraph() at /home/bbcmanagement/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Module/DependencyChecker.php:95 Magento\Framework\Module\DependencyChecker->checkDependencyGraph() at /home/bbcmanagement/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Module/DependencyChecker.php:82 Magento\Framework\Module\DependencyChecker->checkDependenciesWhenEnableModules() at /home/bbcmanagement/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Status.php:97 Magento\Framework\Module\Status->checkConstraints() at /home/bbcmanagement/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/AbstractModuleManageCommand.php:92 Magento\Setup\Console\Command\AbstractModuleManageCommand->execute() at /home/bbcmanagement/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:257 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /home/bbcmanagement/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:874 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /home/bbcmanagement/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:195 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /home/bbcmanagement/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php:96 Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun() at /home/bbcmanagement/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:126 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /home/bbcmanagement/public_html/bin/magento:23

>module:enable [-f|--force] [--all] [-c|--clear-static-content] [--magento-init-params="..."] [module1] ... [moduleN] }
```

> **app\code\BBC\ProductAdminAccess\composer.json**

```
{"name": "bbc/sample-module-minimal",
  "description": "A module that creates a page in the Magento admin area",
  "type": "magento2-module",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
  ],
  "require": {
    "php": "~5.6.0|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "files": [ "registration.php" ],
    "psr-4": {
      "BBC\\ProductAdminAccess\\": ""
    }
  }}
```

> **app\code\BBC\ProductAdminAccess\registration.php**

```
    <?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'BBC_ProductAdminAccess',
    __DIR__);
```

I have checked the format of the json file using online format checker and it came out fine.

Please help Me with it.

[image]

Comment: check your `composer.json` file content.

Comment: @kunj : I have added the composer and registration.php code, can you take a look, I have checked the format of the json file using online format checker and it came out fine.

Comment: try this `{"name": "bbc/product-admin-access",
  "description": "A module that creates a page in the Magento admin area",
  "type": "magento2-module",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
  ],
  "require": {
    "php": "~5.6.0|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "files": [ "registration.php" ],
    "psr-4": {
      "BBC\\ProductAdminAccess\\": ""
    }
  }}`

Comment: @kunj : It didn't worked, got the same error, anything else that you can suggest me.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried the below code and it worked fine.

```
php bin/magento module:enable -f  BBC_ProductAdminAccess
```